# How to build a simple C++ demo using Eigen with Bazel?

Tags: c++, eigen, bazel

How can I use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) within a C++ project that is built using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) (version 0.25.2)? I like to fetch the Eigen dependency using `http_archive` or `git_repository`.

I've tried the following:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int main() {
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m(0, 0) = 3;
    m(1, 0) = 2.5;
    m(0, 1) = -1;
    m(1, 1) = m(1, 0) + m(0, 1);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

*WORKSPACE*

```
workspace(name = "EigenDemo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# Eigen
http_archive(
    name = "eigen",
    build_file = "//:eigen.BUILD",
    sha256 = "3a66f9bfce85aff39bc255d5a341f87336ec6f5911e8d816dd4a3fdc500f8acf",
    url = "https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/c5e90d9.tar.gz",
)
```

*BUILD*

```
cc_binary(
    name = "EigenDemo",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@eigen",
    ],
)
```

*eigen.BUILD*

```
# Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS-IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

package(
    default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "eigen",
    hdrs = glob(
        ["Eigen/**"],
        exclude = [
            "Eigen/src/OrderingMethods/Amd.h",
            "Eigen/src/SparseCholesky/**",
            "Eigen/Eigen",
            "Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers",
            "Eigen/MetisSupport",
            "Eigen/Sparse",
            "Eigen/SparseCholesky",
            "Eigen/SparseLU",
        ],
    ),
    defines = [
        "EIGEN_MPL_ONLY",
        "EIGEN_NO_DEBUG",
    ],
    includes = ["."],
)
```

Error output:

```
INFO: Analysed target //:EigenTest (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /BazelDemos/EigenDemo/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//:EigenTest' failed (Exit 1) gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF ... (remaining 40 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Dense>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Target //:EigenTest failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.258s, Critical Path: 0.10s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Never used bazel, but the error message looks like the extra comma(s) behind `"@eigen//:eigen"` are the problem.

Comment: @chtz: I edited my post - the double comma happened accidently - I updated the error message

Comment: I guess this requires somebody who actually knows bazel ... Maybe clearing the/some cache helps?

Comment: Did bazel clean --expunge_async && bazel build //...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strip_prefix` is missing in the `WORKSPACE` file:

```
workspace(name = "EigenDemo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# Eigen
http_archive(
    name = "eigen",
    build_file = "//:eigen.BUILD",
    sha256 = "3a66f9bfce85aff39bc255d5a341f87336ec6f5911e8d816dd4a3fdc500f8acf",
    url = "https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/c5e90d9.tar.gz",
    strip_prefix="eigen-eigen-c5e90d9e764e"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow no longer uses a separate eigen.BUILD file. Instead, you can put the following in your WORKSPACE file (without the need for a separate eigen.BUILD file):

```
http_archive(
    name = "com_gitlab_libeigen_eigen",
    sha256 = "0215c6593c4ee9f1f7f28238c4e8995584ebf3b556e9dbf933d84feb98d5b9ef",
    strip_prefix = "eigen-3.3.8",
    urls = [
        "https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.8/eigen-3.3.8.tar.bz2",
    ],
    build_file_content =
"""
# TODO(keir): Replace this with a better version, like from TensorFlow.
# See https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/issues/337.
cc_library(
    name = 'eigen',
    srcs = [],
    includes = ['.'],
    hdrs = glob(['Eigen/**']),
    visibility = ['//visibility:public'],
)
"""
)
```

(As you can probably tell from the TODO, I ripped this from Ceres.)

Answer (score 0):

I used the latest `rules_foreign_cc`. There is a new cmake rule. Here is what I have:

WORKPSPACE

```
workspace(name="bazelt")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "6041f1374ff32ba711564374ad8e007aef77f71561a7ce784123b9b4b88614fc",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-0.8.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/0.8.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

# This sets up some common toolchains for building targets. For more details, please see
# https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.8.0/flatten.html#rules_foreign_cc_dependencies
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

_ALL_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""
http_archive(
  name="eigen",
  build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
  strip_prefix = "eigen-3.4",
  urls=["https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.4/eigen-3.4.tar.bz2"],
  sha256 = "a6f7aaa7b19c289dfeb33281e1954f19bf2ba1c6cae2c182354d820f535abef8",
)
```

BUILD

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")
cmake(
    name = "eigen",
    cache_entries = {
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-fPIC",
    },
    lib_source = "@eigen//:all_srcs",
    out_headers_only = True,
    includes = ["eigen3/",],
    install = True,
)
cc_binary(
    name = "bazelt",
    srcs = [
        "main.cpp",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":eigen",],
)
```

Note the `"includes"` parameter in the cmake rule. By default cmake rule will put the header files in the "include" directory in the cache. So all you need is the relative path to that.
And the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd m = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(4,6);
  std::cout << m << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```